# Vuex removes state id key value pair on mutation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuex

My Vue app has the following state

```
saving: false,
saveStatus: 0,
validationErrors: [],
record: {
    createdAt:"2017-04-22T16:17:14.825Z"
    email:"isreyakenobi@starwars.com.au"
    id:"BFCD7EC9-094D-4A97-BDFD-5C7D9D9F092A"
    mobile:"12345678"
    name:"Rey QuestionMark"
    phone:"94801234"
    type:"Customer"
    updatedAt:"2017-04-25T18:38:21.101Z"
}
```

I have a component which fires the `saveCustomer` action when a user completed a form updating the customer's email.

```
saveCustomer = async ({ commit, state }, customer) => {
    commit(types.SAVE_CUSTOMER)

    const response = await api.put(
        'customers',
        customer
    )

    if (response instanceof Error) {
        // If parameters passed are invalid
        if (response.response.status === config.errorStatusCodes.badRequest) {
            commit(types.SAVE_CUSTOMER_INVALID, Object.values(response.response.data.message))
            return
        }

        commit(types.SAVE_CUSTOMER_FAILURE)
        return
    }

    commit(types.CUSTOMER_SAVED, response.data)
    commit(types.CANCEL_EDIT_CUSTOMER)
}
```

Upon the api returning a `Bad Request` response as so

```
{  
    "statusCode":"400",
    "statusText":"Bad Request",
    "name":"",
    "message":{  
        "email":"\"email\" is not correctly formatted."
    }
}
```

The `SAVE_CUSTOMER_INVALID` mutation does not touch the `record` in the state but rather mutates other aspects of the state.

```
[types.SAVE_CUSTOMER_INVALID] (state, errors) {
    state.saving = false
    state.saveStatus = config.saveStatuses.invalid
    state.validationErrors = errors
}
```

For some reason the `id` key value pair is stripped from the `record` in the state when this mutation is committed. Every other key value pair is persisted.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Why don't you show `SAVE_CUSTOMER_INVALID` code then? The object can't mutate for no reason.

Comment: @wostex Check my edit, doesn't touch the record.